# Issue in copying HEX data from ORACLE db (source) to AZURE SQL (sink) through ADF

Tags: oracle, azure, hex, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

**Scenario:**

I am trying to copy data from source ORACLE database to sink AZURE SQL using ADF.
I have created Oracle 11gR2 database in my local system (Windows 10) and installed Self Hosted Run time. On adding "data set" in ADF, I can "preview" tables from my local Oracle database.
Now target is Azure SQL and copy activity is like-to-like. So I have created table in AZURE SQL, keeping all column attributes same, barring one RAW column in source.

**Problem:**

In source table, there is a column of type RAW(2000) and it contains zlib compressed data in HEX format.
For this, as per the mapping spec detailed in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/non-sql/data-type-mapping-for-oracle-publishers?view=sql-server-ver15,
I have changed the type for the same field in Azure SQL to varbinary(2000) (also tried with binary(2000)
Source column data in Oracle is as below:

```
COMPRESS_DATA
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
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
```

Now when I am creating the copy step in ADF and in Mapping tab, I opt for "Import Schema", it shows:
for Source, COMPRESS DATA field type is BYTE[ ].
Naturally when I run the pipeline, the above column value comes in Azure SQL, in a different format:
[data preview in ADF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdC8L.png)
**Data as in ADF preview and in Azure SQL (post copy)**

```
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
```

Expected outcome:
The content should be copied to Azure SQL as is from source (HEX).

Please help/advice on how this can be achieved as we are planning to move 10TB of Oracle data into Azure SQL but this is the base issue blocking it.

Comment: can you try manually mapping `RAW(2000)` to Azure SQL database `nvarchar(max)` data type?

Comment: Hi @LeonYue you mean in the ADF copy activity? where we have source to target mapping? I could see only the column can be selected from the UI (not the TYPE). I can edit the ADF Pipeline JSON and manually put type": "RAW"? Is that you are suggesting?

Comment: Hi @Rahul Roy,yes, I mean manually set that during the sink mapping. If we couldn't, can you try create the table with nvarchar(max) data type to accept the data from Oracle?

Comment: Hi @LeonYue - thanks a lot. Changing it to NVARCHAR(MAX) while creating the Azure SQL table solved the problem.
I first kept the intermediate type in ADF JSON as-is i.e. ByteArray and the above change of NVARCHAR worked. I also changed the intermediate type to RAW explicitly and still NVARCHAR change was enough. Thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: You're welcome. If my answer is helpful for you, please accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try create the table with nvarchar(max) data type in Azure SQL database.

I'm glad to hear that "Changing it to NVARCHAR(MAX) while creating the Azure SQL table solved the problem".

It's my pleasure to help you!